# Android - How to show created user in Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i'm trying to show the created user/user info in my firestore database but i cant seem to get it. I have a Question `model` already created that will show up whenever a new question is submitted however when I try to create a `user`, the information doesnt show in the Database.

Ideally, of course, i'd like to have the info in the database. i'd also like to show that the question was created by an author.

Any and all help is appreciated. Ive been following a series of tutorials trying to blend them all to make my code work but im struggling on this part.

here is my relative code so far:

`SignUpActivity.java`

```
private void registerUser() {

        final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        final String userName = editTextUserName.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        final List<Question> questionsList = new ArrayList<>();

        final String firstName = "default firstName";
        final String lastName = "default lastName";    

        CollectionReference usersRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users");
        User userInfo = new User(userName, firstName, lastName, email, questionsList);
//        DocumentReference docPath = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document(mAuth.getCurrentUser()).
        userInfo.setUserName(userName);

            usersRef.add(userInfo);    

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {


                    CollectionReference usersRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users");
                    usersRef.add(new User(userName, firstName, lastName, email, questionsList));

                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            if (user != null) {
                                UserProfileChangeRequest profileChangeRequest = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                        .setDisplayName(userName).build();
                                user.updateProfile(profileChangeRequest);

                            }
                        }
                    };

                    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener); // need this to change info on Firebase Firestore

                    String usernameTest = user.getDisplayName();

                    Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "info saved hopefully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    finish();
                    startActivity(new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class));


                } else {

                    if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are already registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

`NewQuestionActivity.java`

```
private void saveQuestion(){
        String questionString = questionEditText.getText().toString();
        String questionAnswerString = answerEditText.getText().toString();
        String authorFirebase = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().toString(); //TODO: HOW TO SET THIS Author
        authorTextView.setText(authorFirebase);

        int priority = numberPickerPriority.getValue();
        String tagInput = editTextTags.getText().toString();
        String[] tagArray = tagInput.split("\\s*, \\s*");
        List<String> tags = Arrays.asList(tagArray);
        if (questionString.trim().isEmpty() || questionAnswerString.trim().isEmpty()) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Please insert a question and a proposed answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        CollectionReference questionRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Questions");
        questionRef.add(new Question(questionString, questionAnswerString, priority, tags, authorFirebase));

        Toast.makeText(this, "Question Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
```

`usermodel`

```
package com.example.stairmaster.models;
import java.util.List;
import androidx.databinding.BaseObservable;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Exclude;

public class User extends BaseObservable {

    @Exclude
    private int id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String userName;
    private String email;
    private List<Question> questions;

    public User() {
        // no arg constructor needed
    }

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String userName, String email, List<Question> questions) {

        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.email = email;
        this.questions = questions;

    }

    public int getId() {

        return id;
    }

    public String getUserName(String userName) { return userName;}


    public void setUserName(String userName) { this.userName = userName; }

    public String getFirstName(String firstName) {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName(String lastName) {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail(String email) {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public List<Question> getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }
}
```

Issue is firstname, and lastname are not being created in the database as they should be. ID is incorrect (i'm still not too sure what to assign as an ID to users so that they unique), and the questions list is another thing i still need to figure out.

[image]

Comment: @Zoe understood. thanks!

Comment: @Cflux What the problem with the shared code?

Comment: @AlexMamo, firstName and lastName arnt being committed to Database and i cant figure out why. i'm setting them to be default strings in my xml file but they are not going through to the firestore when i register the user. 

On a side note, i just found your tutorials on youtube for this stuff so im trying to cross compare my stuff with yours but it seems like i have everything in yours up to the end of lesson 6 : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UIRt9Ts0fRU&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=6

Comment: @Cflux None of your users has the firstname and lastname set?

Comment: @AlexMamo nope, none of them.  on the signup screen, you only declare your username, email, and password. I can get the emulator to display the username and email in the userProfile page i have set up, but neither the username or the email is carried on into the database.

Comment: @Cflux How is the `id` added since you are using `@Exclude`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192675/discussion-between-cflux-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: 3 months later and still trying to solve this :-/

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working. although the only thing i cant seem to get working is storing the userId when its created so i have to do that later somewhere.

Code under registerUser looks like this now:

```
        final CollectionReference usersColRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users");
        final User userInfo = new User(firstName, lastName, userName, userEmail, mAuthUserId);
        final DocumentReference userDocRef = usersColRef.document(userEmail);

        userDocRef.set(userInfo).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                mAuthUserId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                userDocRef.update(
                        "firstname", firstName,
                        "lastname", lastName,
                        "userEmail", userEmail).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: userinfo was created");
                    }
                });
                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: user was created");

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: failed to create user in signup" + e);
            }
        });
```